# mongo db - efficient way to search strings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am looking to search strings that are broken up into a prefix, numbers and letters, I currently need to search 55 million rows and a row looks like this (I also save a concatanated version of the entire string):

`{  "prefix" : "AA", "numbers" : "02", "letters" : "AFO", "code" : "AA02AFO" "price" : "699" }`

What is the most efficient way of searching if I want a combined search which will match the above exactly but also return matches like:

```
AA*AFO
A*AFO
*A02AFO
**02AFO
```

And so on, I want to return an exact match if this exists and I also want to return any records which are similar to the search record as well.

I currently have an index on all the fields except price and an index on the concatanated code. Is there also a way to ensure the query returns distinct results if a string matches multiple regexs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, constructing this query as a regular expression against a string is going to be one of the least efficient ways of querying. Instead, you should query by the actual fields:

```js
{
$or: [
  {prefix: "AA", numbers: "02", "letters": "AFO"}, -- full match
  {prefix: {$exists: true}, numbers: "02", "letters: "AFO" } -- varying prefix,
   ...etc
]}
```

Querying by the actual fields will allow Mongo to efficiently use indexes. A regular expression like `/^..02AFO/` will require checking every single record in the index for matches.

> I currently have an index on all the fields except price and an index on the concatanated code. Is there also a way to ensure the query returns distinct results if a string matches multiple regexs?

If you did want to match against regular expressions, you could use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions) to combine multiple regular expressions & return only unique matching documents: `{code: {$in: [/foo/, /bar/] }`

You could also use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/): `{$or: [{code: /foo/}, {code: /bar/}], otherCriterion: "yay"}`.

Comment: I did think that a regex might be very slow, I think I might need to go back to the drawing board but I will give the combination of these two posts a go to see how it performs. As far indexes go would you index each individual field, I reread my post and what I meant is I have a composite index of all the fields and one on the concatanated column? The indexes are going to require a lot of ram!

Comment: If you use `explain` on the regex queries, you should see that it's going do be examining every single document in the collection. If you have 3 fields, a, b, and c and are querying by `{a, b, c}`, `{a, b}`, `{a, c}` and `{b, c}`, you should normally get acceptable performance with 2 indexes: `a.b.c` and `b.c`

Comment: Alternatively, you could start storing the string queries that a document should match *on the document itself* & index that. That way, you can index that array field with a multikey index & get fast look-ups there.

Comment: I am getting pretty fast responses without the need to use regexes, I am just searching on indexed fields. One change I made after your suggestion was to split the entire string into individual fields. I am getting aroudn 2s response times for a search of the 55 milllion records which returns to me around 5000 matches so I feel that is good. Is it possible to indicate the order of the returned results using or? It doesnt seem they are returned in the order I am passing in the objects.

Comment: Down to 380ms now!

Comment: That's great! I think it's going to be hard to use a sort to return the documents in the order that you're querying, but docs are here -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator to test each individual regex. You can cross-reference the results via the record's `code` to see if it is in multiple results:

```
const regexes = [
  /AA*AFO/,
   ...
];

const results = {};

regexes.forEach(async (regex) => {
  results[regex] = await db.collection.find(
    {
      code: {
        $regex: regex
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would second Willis's answer and suggest that you do exact matches on each of the components of the string. However, if that's not flexible enough (i.e. you want to be able to do partial matches *within* each component as well), I'd recommend setting up a mirrored ElasticSearch engine, especially given how many records you have. MongoDB isn't really designed to do efficient freeform text searching.

My own personal experience was that with about 10 million records, even with indexing the concatenated string field, doing freeform searching was taking >30sec per query, even with enough RAM to hold the (pretty big) index. As I was trying to do realtime auto-complete on a text field, that wouldn't work :-)

ElasticSearch has several solutions for replicating data from mongodb into its own database automatically, so I found once I set everything up, it went pretty smoothly. I use monstache (https://github.com/rwynn/monstache) but there are others as well. I realize this is not exactly what you asked for, but I went through a painful process of trying to optimize mongodb for freeform text searching that didn't take forever and ultimately gave up. If this is going to be a common query, and you need decent performance, I highly suggest looking into something like ElasticSearch that's optimized for it.

Comment: Not its a very viable option and I had thought of perhaps using elastic search or something else but hadnt gone any further than that as I was very new toi mongo itself and was trying to limit the amount of extra things to learn in a short time frame. given what you have said about your experiences with free text searching I might have no choice as ~30s or more response times are far too slow.